# How to find all instances of @[XX:XXXX] in a string and then find the surrounding text?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, ruby-on-rails-3

Given a string like:

```
"@[19:Sara Mas] what's the latest with the TPS report? @[30:Larry Peters] can you help out here?"
```

I want to find a way to dynamically return, the user tagged and the content surrounding. Results should be:

```
user_id: 19
copy: what's the latest with the TPS report?

user_id: 30
copy: can you help out here?
```

Any ideas on how this can be done with ruby/rails? Thanks

How is this regex for finding matches?

```
@\[\d+:\w+\s\w+\]
```

Comment: rubular might help w @[XX:XXXXX] but not looping through or finding the surrounding content right?

Comment: I have this for the regex, @\[\d+:\w+\s\w+\]  but now where do I go?

Comment: To answer your below question regarding capturing matches independent of the order of the user information and the content:  

Yes, it is always possible.  However, it is much more challenging a problem. That's much less trivial to handle.  Can you provide explicit examples of both behaviors?  Maybe some raw response data?

Comment: Do you really count on there always being punctuation? Also, the answer won't capture the case where your report comes like this: `what's the latest with the TPS report? @[19:Sara Mas]`.  Did I understand you correctly that your input might come in that form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
result = subject.scan(/\[(\d+).*?\](.*?)(?=@|\Z)/m)
```

This grabs id and content in backreferences 1 and 2 respectively. For stoping the capture either @ or the end of string must be met.

```
 "
\\[         # Match the character “[” literally
(          # Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1
   \\d         # Match a single digit 0..9
      +          # Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
)
.          # Match any single character that is not a line break character
   *?         # Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy)
\\]         # Match the character “]” literally
(          # Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 2
   .          # Match any single character that is not a line break character
      *?         # Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy)
)
(?=        # Assert that the regex below can be matched, starting at this position (positive lookahead)
              # Match either the regular expression below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails)
      \@          # Match the character “\@” literally
   |          # Or match regular expression number 2 below (the entire group fails if this one fails to match)
      \$          # Assert position at the end of the string (or before the line break at the end of the string, if any)
)
"
```

This will match something starting from @ and ending to punctuation makr. Sorry if I didn't understand correctly.

```
result = subject.scan(/@.*?[.?!]/)
```

Comment: Thanks, just tried that. Couple issues. the number 19 or 30 is the user.id so it can be from 1 to infinity integers long. Also, if the string is "What's the deal with the reports @[30:Larry Peters]" the above returns "" as the content. Is there a way for content to get the entire sentence where the match was made?

Comment: Only handles 2 digit user ids.

Comment: @Ryanmt I didn't see an example with a larger count of digits. This trivial thing can simply be corrected with \d+. Thanks for the tip though..

Comment: @RachelaMeadows You've specified in your above examples a pattern of the user info prefacing a comment, is that not true?

Comment: @FailedDev I know; I just wanted to ensure that was noted, but OP beat me to mentioning it regardless.

Comment: regarding prefacing, it could be prefacing or not. Could go either way

Comment: Is it possible for now just to get the entire sentence where the @ was included? everything from the left to the right surrounding the match and a punctuation mark?

Comment: Yes it's possible. From @ to @? Exluding the second @?

Comment: I'd like to include the entire sentence where the @ was included... Sentence being from start to end of a punctiontion: ?.!

Comment: @RachelaMeadows Please check my updated answer. If it needs modifying let me know!

Answer (score 2):

Split the string, then handle the content iteratively.  I don't think it'd take more than:

```
tmp = string.split('@').map {|str| [str[/\[(\d*).*/,1], str[/\](.*^)/,1]] }
tmp.first #=> ["19", "what's the latest with the TPS report?"]
```

Does that help?

Comment: Interesting, thanks why split the string? It would be nice to find all locations where the regex matches. And then grab the surrounding content either to the right up until the first sign of a punctuation mark (period, question mark, exclamation point). Ideas?

Comment: Sure, that is possible. I think this is simpler to debug, and probably less difficult to read later, when you've forgotten what the REGEX was supposed to do.